# Struggling to figure out where to insert perentheses

Tags: python, math

Hey guys I need to figure out where the parentheses fit into this code for the following expression and am a little confused to where the parentheses actually goes into. I keep getting it wrong.

[Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv8Bg.png)

```
x = float(input('Enter a value for x: '))

# Insert parentheses in the following line to fix the expression.
y = x - 1 ** 0.5 + 1 / 5

print('y = ' + str(y))
```

Comment: This seems like more of a maths question than a programming question. How would you do the order of operations on the equation you posted? What steps would you follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
y = ( ( (x - 1 ) ** 0.5 ) + 1 ) / 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses around the square root and the numerator should be clear.

```
y = ((x-1)**0.5 + 1) / 5
```

Additionally, you could import 'math'. This lets you use sqrt() as follows:

```
y = (math.sqrt(x-1) + 1) / 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the order of evaluation in python, you actually need three sets of them.

Like this :

```
y = (((x - 1) ** 0.5) + 1 )/ 5
```